# Processing results from multiple tables - is there a faster way?

Tags: sqlite, caching

I'm just trying to improve my Database structure in order to avoid getting cloned results
My tables sits it one Database and looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Players`(
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `UserID`    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `SteamID`   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `Nick`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `KlanID`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Money` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Kills` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Deaths`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Score` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `PayOrNot`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `IsNewOne`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `HUDMode`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `HUDColors` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `HUDPoz1` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `HUDPoz2`   INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Classes` (
    `ClassID`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    `UserID`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Level` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Health`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Intelligence`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Stamina`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Durability`    INTEGER NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE `Equipment` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `UserID`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `Type`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `Time`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `NumberOfUses`  INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

It is a plugin designed for a Counter Strike server. It introduces some extra functionalities such as choosing own class, receiving equipment which gives extra powers, leveling system etc etc. I need to get almost all of the data stored there. The problem is, the amount of  Equipment of each player is not known. Therefore, i have to figure out how to get these informations as optimal as i can.

For now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Players.SteamID,Players.Nick,Players.KlanID,Players.Money,Players.Kills,Players.Deaths,Players.Score,Players.PayOrNot,Players.IsNew,Players.HUDMode,Players.HUDColors,Players.HUDPoz1,Players.HUDPoz2,
                Classes.Name,Classes.Level,Classes.Health,Classes.Intelligence,Classes.Stamina,Classes.Durability,
                Equipment.Name,Equipment.Type,Equipment.Time,Equipment.NumberOfUses 
FROM Players
INNER JOIN Equipment ON Players.UserID   = Equipment.UserID
INNER JOIN Classes   ON Equipment.UserID = Classes.UserID
WHERE Players.UserID=%d
```

[Here are some sample results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Qjq.png)
(don't be scared by some of the words out there - I come originally from Poland. The things needed has beed translated and highlighted)

Every time map changes, each player has to receive this data + there might be some new ones throughout the map.
As you can see, there are some field copies due to the INNER JOIN nature. Luckily, I am able to process the results, because i know the number of classes, so i get the Equipment from [row % number_of_classes] rows and Classes from [row < number_of_classes] rows. However, i feel it could be done better. I was thinking about getting results from each query separately, but it would triple the number of queries. Maybe I have to rebuild the whole SQL structure? Or maybe this is the best way to do so?

Comment: (1) Your question is too complicated.  (2) Your code cannot be read.  (3) Choose which database you are really using.

Comment: Done. The questions itself are pretty simple, I just added some explanatory to clarify what my intensions are

Comment: Asking more than question would be too broad. (And nobody knows how fast your machine is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of a single query has the form of a table, i.e., it has a fixed number of columns, and a certain number of rows.
If you want to get your data with a single query, you have no choice but to arrange it so that is has tabular form. When joining, this often results in duplicates.

But there is no reason to use a single query. SQLite has no client/server communication overhead, so [many small queries are just as efficient](http://www.sqlite.org/np1queryprob.html).